# Search Key/Value Inside Nested Objects (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to find a object value inside a nested object, this object has a lot o level's and this specific object value that i want it's not always in the same level inside the object.

What i'm trying to do is:

```
//ArrayofCoordinates it's the array of the objects that i want to search my value inside of each of this objects.

let coordinatesToAddArray = [];
arrayOfCoordinates.map(coordinateObject => {
            let coordinateData = findObjectNested(coordinateObject, 'tagName', 'text'); //'tagName' it's the key that i'm looking for and 'text' it's the value of the 'tagName' key that i'm looking for.
            if(coordinateData) {
                coordinatesToAddArray.push(coordinateData);
            }
        });

//This is the recursive function that i created to search inside the object for the specific value and return him, but all i get from the return of this function it's a undefined.

function findObjectNested(entireObj, keyToFind, valueToFind) {

    if(entireObj && entireObj[keyToFind] === valueToFind) {
        return entireObj;
    } else {
        if(entireObj['children'].length > 0) {
            entireObj['children'].map(objectsOfChildren => {
                findObjectNested(objectsOfChildren, keyToFind, valueToFind);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I know that the recursive function it's working because when i replace the "return entireObj" to "console.log(entireObj)" i can see the object that i'm looking for, but when i'm trying to return this object all i get it's a undefined.

I believe that this has something to do with the recursive function.

Anyone can help me with any tips about how to solve this problem?

Thank you so much.

Comment: You don't return the result of the recursive call, and you don't return the result of `map()`

Comment: Also, `map()` will return an array of results, and they'll contain nested arrays of results, etc.